# Some of my netbook keyboard keys are totally unresponsive

Tags: keyboard, netbook, unresponsive

My samsung n130 netbook keyboard keys suddenly stopped working. The keys are 4,5,6,7 e, r, y, u, i, o, j, k, n. Please dont advice me to clean my keyboard as I have already did. I was hoping to cut the ribbon cable any advice on this?

Comment: How would cutting the cable fix it?? Do you mean to replace it? I wouldn't have thought you would need to cut any wires to replace a keyboard.

Comment: No i mean i would like to cut or trim some cm to the end of the cable.

Comment: How would that solve the problem? I guess I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the person means trim the end of the ribbon and re-insert to make a fresh connection. If the  keyboard is not working and may need replacing anyway, then what do you have to lose?

*But* you could first try downloading a new driver. The unit can be hard to get in to and there is also a 99% chance that the on switch will be smashed when putting back together, only to find that your d.i.y. snip it job didnt actually work! Find your local backstreet computer shop and let those guys sort it.